# Migrate exoplayer exoplayer.downloadService.action.RESTART to media3

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

The Exoplayer states this requirement for "MyDownloadService"

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.exoplayer.downloadService.action.RESTART"/>
```

How to migrate it to media3? I couldn't find the RESTART on their documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/exoplayer/offline/DownloadService

Answer (score 1):

Found it

```
androidx.media3.exoplayer.downloadService.action.RESTART
```